# Twisted Matrix Callback with parameters

Tags: matrix, parameters, callback, twisted

How can I add parameters to a callback call?

i.e.

> def test(x,y,z)
>    ...
>     ...
>
> myobjectx.addCallback(test)

this pass myobjectx as x but how can I add the others parameters y,z?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Deferred howto](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#auto11) tells you how to do this.  So does the [Deferred API documentation](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.html).